# How to stop text from moving from element

Tags: html, css, responsiveness

I am currently trying to make responsible my website. I need to make this responsive. I made it mainly for full HD monitors (1920px) but if I make browser smaller it is bad looking.

```css
.container .banner {
  width: 55vw;
  height: 15vw;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  margin-left: 15vw;
  margin-top: -42.5vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  background-image: url('../../files/imgs/lobby.png');
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container .banner img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20vw;
  width: 30vw;
  margin-top: -2.7vw;
  margin-left: 12.75vw;
}

.container .status {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 20vw;
  max-width: 30vw;
  min-height: 15vw;
  max-height: 30vw;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: white;
  left: 60vw;
  top: -15vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

.container .status h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container .status .teamspeak3 img {
  margin-left: 1vw;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 3vw;
  height: 3vw;
  min-width: 1vw;
  min-height: 1vw;
}

.container .status .teamspeak3 .online {
  margin-top: -3vw;
  margin-left: 4.5vw;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.container .status .teamspeak3 .number {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: -1.95vw;
  margin-left: 7.3vw;
}

.container .status .discord img {
  margin-left: 0.75vw;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 3.25vw;
  height: 3.25vw;
  background: #5865F259;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(88, 101, 242, 0.55);
  animation: discord-pulse 2s infinite;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: scale(1);
}

@keyframes discord-pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(88, 101, 242, 0.35);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.75vw rgba(88, 101, 242, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(88, 101, 242, 0);
  }
}

.container .status .discord .onlinestatus {
  margin-top: -3vw;
  margin-left: 4.5vw;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.container .status .discord .number {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: -2vw;
  margin-left: 7.3vw;
}

.container .status .discord .address {
  margin-top: -1vw;
  margin-left: 4.5vw;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container .status .minecraft img {
  margin-top: 1.75vw;
  margin-left: 0.75vw;
  width: 3.25vw;
  height: 3.25vw;
  background: #969892;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(150, 152, 146, 0.55);
  animation: minecraft-pulse 2s infinite;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: scale(1);
}

@keyframes minecraft-pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(150, 152, 146, 0.35);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.75vw rgba(150, 152, 146, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(150, 152, 146, 0);
  }
}

.container .status .minecraft .onlinestatus {
  margin-top: -3vw;
  margin-left: 4.5vw;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.container .status .minecraft .number {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: -2vw;
  margin-left: 7.3vw;
}

.container .status .minecraft .address {
  margin-top: -3vw;
  margin-left: 4.5vw;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container .status .offline {
  background: rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
  animation: offline-pulse 2s infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -2.6vw;
  margin-left: 12vw;
  height: 1.25vw;
  width: 1.25vw;
  transform: scale(1);
}

@keyframes offline-pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 0.7);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
  }
}

.container .status .online {
  background: rgba(51, 217, 178, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(51, 217, 178, 1);
  animation: online-pulse 2s infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -2.6vw;
  margin-left: 12vw;
  height: 1.25vw;
  width: 1.25vw;
  transform: scale(1);
}

@keyframes online-pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(51, 217, 178, 0.7);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(51, 217, 178, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(51, 217, 178, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="status">
  <h2>STATUS</h2>
  <div class="discord">
    <img src="./files/imgs/discord.svg" alt="">
    <p class="onlinestatus">Online: </p>
    <p class="number">999</p>
    <p class="address">mc.dialand.eu</p>
    <div class="offline"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="minecraft">
    <img src="./files/imgs/minecraft.webp" alt="">
    <p class="onlinestatus">Online: </p>
    <p class="number">999</p>
    <a class="address" onclick="copyMCaddress()">mc.dialand.eu</a>
    <div class="online"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are looking to make a site/page responsive, you should look into [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). This will allow you to modify the CSS based on things like screen size.

Comment: Yeah i know about that. But i don't know how to work with it there.

Comment: This is also a good resource and a bit easier to follow than the (more authoritative) MDN documentation https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: There is what happens when i have it smallest i can have. https://imgur.com/a/QDw4VrP

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post to ask a more specific question. "Responsive" isn't a clear description. Tell us exactly which elements are a problem and how.

Comment: Okay but how i should do it in media queries? i don't have idea.

Comment: I'd start looking at styling your divs using flexbox. You can then use a media query to stack them vertically at small screen sizes. Some info on flexbox here. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: All things in element <div class="minecraft"> and in element <div class="discord">.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at the w3schools link above. It will walk you through what they are and how they work. Then have a play around with it.

Comment: Okey, inline-flex helped and quite a lot. And i have one more question. How to make one thing (for example this status) to be under another element (for example banner) only if width is smaller then both of them (+ menu on the left)

Comment: If you use flexbox you can set flex-direction: column and that will stack divs on top of each other.